# Minimize sum of squared errors or its mean

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, error

Is there any difference in minimizing the sum of squared errors in a linear regression model learning, compared to minimizing the mean of the sum of squared errors, apart from having easier math when calculating the derivative of the error function?

The formula I am talking about is:

$$Error_{\theta} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(\left(y_i - \left(\theta^T \cdot x_i \right) \right)^2 \right)$$

And usually the following is the minimization problem:

$$\underset{\theta}{\min} \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(\left(y_i - \left(\theta^T \cdot x_i \right) \right)^2 \right) \right)$$

or add a $2$ to make derivation easier:

$$\underset{\theta}{\min} \left( \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(\left(y_i - \left(\theta^T \cdot x_i \right) \right)^2 \right) \right)$$

Wouldn't

$$\underset{\theta}{\min} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(\left(y_i - \left(\theta^T \cdot x_i \right) \right)^2 \right) \right)$$

work just as well?

Comment: Yes, minimising a function is the same as minimising that function multiplied by a positive constant. Or in fact any strictly increasing transformation of the function.